# Remove gradient from subview on rotation

Tags: ios, swift, gradient, layer

I can remove the gradient from the subview fine, But If a button is added to the subview I can not remove the gradient layer. How can I Remove gradient from subview on rotation.

Here is the code for the View Controller.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mySubView: UIView!   
    @IBOutlet weak var mySubView2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mySubView3: UIView!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
         addGradient()
    }

    fileprivate func addGradient() {
        mySubView.mainGradientBackground()
        mySubView2.subGradientBackground()
        mySubView3.subGradientBackground()
        labelOutlet.labelTextfieldShadow()
        buttonOutlet.buttonGradientBackground(cornerRadius: 10, shadowRadius: 3)
    }

     /// This will let you know when the device rotates.
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
       if UIDevice.current.orientation.isValidInterfaceOrientation {

            removeSublayer(mySubView, layerIndex: 0)
            removeSublayer(mySubView, layerIndex: 0)

            removeSublayer(mySubView2, layerIndex: 0)
            removeSublayer(mySubView2, layerIndex: 0)

            removeSublayer(mySubView3, layerIndex: 0)
            removeSublayer(mySubView3, layerIndex: 0)

            removeSublayer(buttonOutlet, layerIndex: 0)
            removeSublayer(buttonOutlet, layerIndex: 0)

            removeSublayer(labelOutlet, layerIndex: 0)
        }
    }


    func removeSublayer(_ view: UIView, layerIndex index: Int) {
        guard let sublayers = view.layer.sublayers else {
            print("The view does not have any sublayers.")
            return
        }
        if sublayers.count > index {
            view.layer.sublayers!.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            print("There are not enough sublayers to remove that index.")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Gradient Extension used to color any views I need.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    /// Use this to set a gradient for the background.
    /// = This is a gradient with no shadow.
    func mainGradientBackground() {
        let color = Color()

        let leading = color.backgroundLeading
        let trailing = color.backgroundTrailing

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [leading, trailing]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0,0.3]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)

        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }

    /// Use this to set a gradient for the background.
    /// = This is a gradient with a shadow.
     func subGradientBackground() {

        let corner: CGFloat = 15
        let color = Color()

        let leading = color.subBackgroundLeading
        let trailing = color.subBackgroundTrailing
        let borderColor = color.subBorderColor

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [leading, trailing]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0,0.3,1]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.borderColor = borderColor
        gradientLayer.borderWidth = 4
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = corner
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

        let subLayer = CALayer()
        subLayer.frame = bounds
        subLayer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: corner - 2).cgPath
        subLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        subLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        subLayer.shadowRadius = 2

        subLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 4)

        layer.insertSublayer(subLayer, at: 0)
    }

      /// Use this to set a gradient for the background.
      /// = This is a gradient with a shadow.
      func subGradientBackgroundShadow() {

          let corner: CGFloat = 15

          let subLayer = CALayer()
          subLayer.frame = bounds
          subLayer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: corner - 2).cgPath
          subLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
          subLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
          subLayer.shadowRadius = 2

          subLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 4)

          layer.insertSublayer(subLayer, at: 0)
      }


    /// LabelShadow
    /// - Parameter masksToBounds: Keep the layer in its bound
    /// - Exp.. Set to true to keep text in textview in its frame.
    /// - Exp.. Set to false to let shadow out side the frame.
    /// - Defalr corner radius is 7
    func labelTextfieldShadow() {
        let color = Color()

        let dark = color.labelBackgroundDark
        let borderColor = color.labelBorderColor

        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        layer.borderColor = borderColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 7
        self.backgroundColor = dark

        layer.shadowRadius = 7
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
    }



    /// Button gradient
    /// - Parameter cornerRadius: Set the radius of the button. Use outlet height / 2
    /// - Parameter shadowRadius: Set the shadow radius. 2
    func buttonGradientBackground(cornerRadius: CGFloat, shadowRadius: CGFloat) {
        let color = Color()

        let leading = color.buttonLeading
        let middle = color.buttonMiddle
        let trailing = color.buttonTrailing
        let borderColor = color.buttonBorderColor

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [leading, middle, trailing]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0,0.3,1]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.borderColor = borderColor
        gradientLayer.borderWidth = 1
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

        let subLayer = CALayer()
        subLayer.frame = bounds
        subLayer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius - 2).cgPath
        subLayer.shadowColor =  UIColor.black.cgColor
        subLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        subLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        subLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 3)
        layer.insertSublayer(subLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Here is four screen shots of the screen.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is a color struct to color all of the views.. Main view, Sub view, Labels and Buttons.

```
struct Color {

    // Use these colors to style the main background.
    /// This color is used for the main view's background leading greadient color.
    let backgroundLeading = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2745098039, green: 0.231372549, blue: 0.231372549, alpha: 1).cgColor

    /// TThis color is used for the main view's background trailing greadient color.
    let backgroundTrailing = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2784313725, green: 0.2352941176, blue: 0.2352941176, alpha: 1).cgColor



    // Use these colors to style the sub view.
    /// This color is used for the sub view's leading greadient color.
    let subBackgroundLeading = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1960784314, green: 0.2549019608, blue: 0.2549019608, alpha: 1).cgColor

    /// This color is used for the sub view's trailing greadient color.
    let subBackgroundTrailing = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1012082246, green: 0.2111029723, blue: 0.1947238818, alpha: 1).cgColor

    /// This color is used for the sub view's border.
    let subBorderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1).cgColor



    // Use these colors to style the labels.
    /// This color is used for editing text background.
    let labelBackgroundLight = #colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1) as UIColor

    /// This color is used for disabled text background.
    let labelBackgroundDark = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1843137255, green: 0.137254902, blue: 0.1384684741, alpha: 1) as UIColor

    /// This color is used for the label's border.
    let labelBorderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6, green: 0.6, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1).cgColor



    // Use these colors to style the buttons.
    /// This color is used for the button's leading greadient color.
    let buttonLeading = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1960784314, green: 0.2549019608, blue: 0.2549019608, alpha: 1).cgColor

    /// This color is used for the button's middle greadient color.
    let buttonMiddle = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1).cgColor

    /// This color is used for the button's trailing greadient color.
    let buttonTrailing = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1012082246, green: 0.2111029723, blue: 0.1947238818, alpha: 1).cgColor

    /// This color is used for the button's border color.
    let buttonBorderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1).cgColor


    // Use these colors for the text
    /// This color is used for the deiabled label and text field.
    let labelDisableColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)

    /// This color is used for the enabled label and text field.
    let labelEnableColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

    /// The text color white.
    let labelWhiteTextColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

    /// The text color Black
    let labelBlackTextColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this was to change each one of the extension to a class. With extension you have to take care of all of the layout your self.  By using these as a class you can set each Button, Sub view Ect... in the storyboard, this way the view itself will redrawing the layout.

```
/// Use this to set a greadient for the background.
/// = This is a greadient with no shadow.
class MainGradientView: UIView {

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    guard let gradientLayer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer else {
        return;
    }
    let color = Color()

    let leading = color.backgroundLeading
    let trailing = color.backgroundTrailing

    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [leading, trailing]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0,0.3]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)
}

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}


}





/// Use this to set a greadient for the background.
/// = This is a greadient with a shadow.
class SubGradientView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    guard let gradientLayer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer else {
        return;
    }

    let corner: CGFloat = 15
    let color = Color()

    let leading = color.subBackgroundLeading
    let trailing = color.subBackgroundTrailing
    let borderColor = color.subBorderColor

    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [leading, trailing]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0,0.3,1]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.borderColor = borderColor
    gradientLayer.borderWidth = 0.4
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = corner

    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 4)
}

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}
}



/// Use this to set a greadient for the background.
/// = This is a greadient with no shadow.
class TabBarGradientView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    guard let gradientLayer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer else {
        return;
    }


    let color = Color()

    let leading = color.buttonLeading
    let middle = color.buttonMiddle
    let trailing = color.buttonTrailing
    let borderColor = color.buttonBorderColor

    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [leading, middle, trailing]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0,0.3,1]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.borderColor = borderColor
    gradientLayer.borderWidth = 1
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 50
}

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}
}


/// Use this to set a greadient for the background.
/// = This is a greadient with a shadow.
class ButtonGradientView: UIButton {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    guard let gradientLayer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer else {
        return;
    }


    let color = Color()

    let leading = color.buttonLeading
    let middle = color.buttonMiddle
    let trailing = color.buttonTrailing
    let borderColor = color.buttonBorderColor

    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [leading, middle, trailing]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0,0.3,1]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.borderColor = borderColor
    gradientLayer.borderWidth = 1
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2

    self.layer.frame = bounds
    self.layer.shadowColor =  UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 3)
}

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}
}


/// Use this to set a greadient for the keypad switch.
/// = This is a greadient with a shadow.
class SwitchGradientView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    guard let gradientLayer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer else {
        return;
    }


    let color = Color()

    let leading = color.buttonLeading
    let middle = color.buttonMiddle
    let trailing = color.buttonTrailing
    let borderColor = color.buttonBorderColor

    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [leading, middle, trailing]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0,0.3,1]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.05, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.borderColor = borderColor
    gradientLayer.borderWidth = 1
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 9

    self.layer.frame = bounds
    self.layer.shadowColor =  UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 3)
}

override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assuming that a layer is at a given index, just retain the laters you want to remove as an instance variable (or in an array of CALayers) and then tell the layer(s) to [remove themselves](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410767-removefromsuperlayer) from their super layer.

For example:

```
var layersToRemoveLater = [CALayer]()
...
layersToRemoveLater.append(someLayer)
layersToRemoveLater.append(someOtherLayer)
...
layersToRemoveLater.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperLayer() }
```